# Improve get "if only one" query

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get if I have only one posted order, but i think i can improve the query using linq. So far I have this:

```
    var orders = await _ordersService.Get(id);
    var ordersPosted = orders?.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Posted.ToString());
    if (ordersPosted == null || !ordersPosted.Any()) return false;

    return ordersPosted.Count() == 1;
```

how can I improve the query in terms of readability and maintenance?

Comment: instead of calling any, why not do `return ordersPosted.Count() == 1`

Comment: if orders do not exist it will return 0

Comment: What do you want to happen if `ordersPosted.Count() == 2`?

Comment: Remove `if (ordersPosted == null ...)` and do just `return ordersPosted?.Count() == 1`

Comment: Remove `var orders = await _ordersService.Get(id);` it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Depending on whether the enumerable is coming from, `var ordersPosted = userInvoices?.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Posted.ToString());` might be improved by using `var bob = Status.Posted.ToString(); var ordersPosted = userInvoices?.Where(x => x.Status == bob);` instead.

Comment: @mjwills yes it is an Enum, and userInvoices can be null

Comment: Your life will be _much_ simpler if you change your methods to return empty rather than null enumerables. Empty enumerables "just work". Null enumerables have no benefit and need lots of gentle hand holding, which invariably you will forget at some point and then BOOM.

Comment: Please show us how `userInvoices` is generated. Depending on where it comes from, other optimisations become possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `Where`. Also the `Count` can have a predicate, such that it counts only the elements, which fulfill the condition. So you can simply do

```
return orders?.Count(x => x.Status == Status.Posted.ToString()) == 1;
```

If `orders` is `null`, then `orders?.Count(...)` will also return `null` and `null == 1` will return `false`.

If `orders` is different from `null`, then `orders?.Count(...)` will return the number of elements in the Enumeration. And thus, it will only return `true` if there is exactly one element in `orders`

You can do alltogether in a oneliner

```
return (await _ordersService.Get(id))?.Count(x => x.Status == Status.Posted.ToString()) == 1;
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @NataliaMuray and @mjwills you can optimize for performance as follows

```
return orders?
  .Where(x => x.Status == Status.Posted.ToString())
  .Take(2)
  .Count() == 1;
```

This will stop searching the `orders` enumeration immediately when a second element is found, whereas `orders?.Count(...)` will iterate over all elements to check the condition.

Comment: Please note that using Linq you are iterating the entire collection, but you could stop early after you found the second invoice. This only matters if the invoice list is capable of getting very large though

Comment: @NataliaMuray It depends partly on the source of the data. If it is an `IQueryable` then `Count` _may_ be reasonable. If it is an `IEnumerable` then you are right - `Take(2)` may be helpful.

Comment: @NataliaMuray OP explicitely stated "improve the query in terms of readability and maintenance" and that seems (to me, but that may be a personal meaning) be more readable than a loop with conditions for stopping early or any other optimized data structure. You are of course right in terms of performance, this solution is far from optimal.

Comment: @mjwills OP asked for improvements on readabilty and maintenance. IMHO (but of course thats just my personal opinion) Linq is more readable than for instance looping with exit conditions. If this query becomes a bottleneck, though, one should of course refactor.

Comment: @mjwills Yes, you are right `Where(...).Take(2)` will stop processing, once when a second element is found. Wil update my answer